# How to Change Elements Classes Independently

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm stumbling in the dark here, so looking for help on how to improve changing of elements css.

Im trying to create two boxes that when clicked change the shade from one color to the next, and then back to the original color.  I've hit a wall trying to now get them to change colors independently.  When I click either element they both change.

Do I need to setup a parent-child relationship? Again, completely in the dark

```css
    p {
      height: 50px;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: #555;
    }
    .rectangles {
      height: 50px;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: #eee;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("p").click(function(){
            $("p").toggleClass("rectangles");
        });
    });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    <p class="rectangles"></p>
    <p class="rectangles"></p>
    
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: instead of using $("p").toggleClass("rectangles");  change it to $(this).toggleClass("rectangles")

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `"p"` to `this`, so that your code becomes `$(this).toggleClass("rectangles");`

This will select only the relevant item.

See below:

```css
    p {
      height: 50px;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: #555;
    }
    .rectangles {
      height: 50px;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: #eee;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("p").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("rectangles");
        });
    });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    <p class="rectangles"></p>
    <p class="rectangles"></p>
    
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```